# Equal Width col-md-4's

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am very new to programming.

I am trying to get three `col-md-4`s to have equal width. I assumed that CSS would not be required for this if Bootstrap was referenced correctly in HTML. Any advice would be much appreciated.

#### Code:

```css
/*NAV LOGO*/

.logo { 
text-decoration: none;
color: black; 
}

.logo img { 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
display: block;
}

/*NAV MENU*/

.menu { 
text-align: center;
}

.menu ul li { 
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
margin-left: 20px; 
margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu ul li a:link { 
 text-decoration: none; 
 background: white;
 color: black;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding-left: 18px; 
 padding-right: 18px; 
 padding-top: 10px; 
 padding-bottom: 10px
 margin-top: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

.menu ul li a:hover { 
background: blue;
color: white;
}

/*SUPPORTING*/



/*FOOTER*/
.footer ul li { 
 color: white;
 list-style-type: none; 
 margin-left: 20px; 
 margin-right: 20px; 
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 0px; 
} 

.footer .container { 
text-align: center;
background: black; 
height: 100px;
}

.footer ul li a:link { 
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.footer p { 
color: white;
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
 <title>WASTEdar | Waste Management and Recycling in Dar es Salaam, Tanzania</title>
</head> 

<body>

 <!--NAV--> 

<div class="nav">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="logo"> 
   <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/53e6b408e4b0cc1fd4cb6a46/54d8bc16e4b050b6c2864e96/54db5b74e4b00d17d9bb0442/1423661993508/wastedar_logos+(1)-page-001.jpg" style="width:505px; height:85px;" align="center"/> 
   <p align="center"><strong>Waste Management and Recycling in Dar es Salaam, Tanzania</strong></p>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
  <div class="center">  
  <ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Programmes</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul> 
     </div> 
     </div> 
 </div> 
</div> 

 <!--SUPPORTING--> 

 <div class="supporting"> 
  <div class="container"> 
   <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <h1>Our Vision</h1>
     <p>We the only NGO operational in Dar es Salaam <br> addressing issues concerning waste management and recycling</p>
     <button type="button" class="btn-btn-default">Learn More</button>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <h1>Our Mission</h1> 
     <p>To clean up Dar es Salaam, Tanzania</p>
     <button type="button" class="btn-btn-default">Learn More</button>
    </div> 

     
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <h1>Our Mission</h1> 
     <p>To clean up Dar es Salaam, Tanzania</p>
     <button type="button" class="btn-btn-default">Learn More</button>
    </div>

   </div> 
  </div>  
 </div> 

 <!--FOOTER-->

 <div class="footer"> 
  <div class="container">
   <ul class="footer"> 
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Programmes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
       <p align="center">Copyright Joshua Palfreman</p>
  </div> 
    </div> 







</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the **bootstrap.css** as well the **bootstrap.js**, I added the `col-xs-4` so you can see those columns having same width in small screens such this snippet.

#### Snippet

```css
/*NAV LOGO*/

.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.logo img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
/*NAV MENU*/

.menu {
  text-align: center;
}
.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.menu ul li a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
/*SUPPORTING*/

/*FOOTER*/

.footer ul li {
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.footer .container {
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
}
.footer ul li a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.footer p {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--NAV-->
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/53e6b408e4b0cc1fd4cb6a46/54d8bc16e4b050b6c2864e96/54db5b74e4b00d17d9bb0442/1423661993508/wastedar_logos+(1)-page-001.jpg" style="width:505px; height:85px;" align="center" />
      <p align="center"><strong>Waste Management and Recycling in Dar es Salaam, Tanzania</strong>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
      <div class="center">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Story</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Programmes</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Resources</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--SUPPORTING-->

<div class="supporting">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <h1>Our Vision</h1>
        <p>We the only NGO operational in Dar es Salaam
          <br>addressing issues concerning waste management and recycling</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn-btn-default">Learn More</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <h1>Our Mission</h1> 
        <p>To clean up Dar es Salaam, Tanzania</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn-btn-default">Learn More</button>
      </div>


      <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <h1>Our Mission</h1> 
        <p>To clean up Dar es Salaam, Tanzania</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn-btn-default">Learn More</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--FOOTER-->

<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="footer">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Story</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Programmes</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Resources</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p align="center">Copyright Joshua Palfreman</p>
  </div>
</div>
```